# Json.net Deserialize Wrapped Types Without Duplicating Code

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

In C#, I'm wrapping primitive types to track what the primitive represents. Here's an example:

```
class Meters {
    public readonly float Value;
    public Meters(float v) { Value = v; }
}
```

I then compose these types into objects:

```
class Box {
    public Meters Width { get; set; }
    public Meters Height { get; set; }
}
```

Using Json.net, I need to deserialize a `Box` from json data that look like this:

```
{
    "Width": 3.23,
    "Height": 2.0
}
```

Can this be done without changing the json to `"Width": { "Value": 3.23 }` and without repeated, boilerplate code for every type like `Meters`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be achieved by adding some [`implicit operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) to the class that can convert a primitive (ie `float`, `decimal`, `double` etc) to your object. Such as.

```
class Meters
{

    public static implicit operator Meters(float value)
    {
        return new Meters(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator Meters(decimal value)
    {
        return new Meters((float)value);
    }

    public static implicit operator Meters(double value)
    {
        return new Meters((float)value);
    }

    public readonly float Value;

    public Meters(float v) { Value = v; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```